# zsh: How to change the color of all invisible file names in the Mac's Terminal?

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors, macos

I'm using a Mac Silicon with the **Ventura** MacOS.  In the Terminal app, all the file names have the same color.  Take note that the default shell is **zsh** in Ventura, and is the one I want to use.  Currently, my **.zshrc** config file has this content (so the directories are all shown with some color in the Terminal.  I don't want to change this):

```
 PROMPT='%U%B%F{red}%n%u: ~%f%b'
 alias ls="ls -G"
 alias ll="ls -lG"
```

The `-G` option in BSD `ls` (also used on macOS) turns on colored output.

I would like to add something in there to change the color used to display hidden files (those whose name starts with a `.`) when using an `ls` option like `-A` that causes them to be shown. I would like all hidden files (but not directories) to be shown in some vivid red color in the Terminal (say magenta).  Please, take note that I'm a noob with the Terminal commands (I only know some basic Unix commands), so I need something simple, no fancy tricks.

So how should I do this?  What commands should I add into my .zshrc file above?

Comment: Do you want to always see hidden files? Or do you want them to be a specific color if you explicitly tell `ls` to list them using `-a` or `-A`?

Comment: @terdon, well, I want to see magenta invisible files as long as I use -a or -A

Comment: So you want to have hidden files (that's what they're called, the ones whose names starts with a `.`) visible but colored? Those are two separate things. To always see hidden files, make a new alias, like the ones you show there, something like `la='ls -A'` and then use `la` instead of `ls`. But please [edit] your question and clarify that you want two things: i) always show hidden files and ii) show them in a specific color.

Comment: @terdon, I don't see why my question isn't clear enough.  I simply need to colorize all the files that start with a dot to some color in the Terminal app.  I don't want these files to become visible in the Finder!  I want the invisible files to be shown with some color in the list, to make them stand by.

Comment: Yes, but `ls` doesn't show these files. So you want two things: you want to see them in the output of `ls` (which is done by using `ls -A`) and you want to set them to a specific color. Finder isn't relevant, we're only discussing the command line.

Comment: @terdon, yes I know that **ls** will not show the invisible files.  That's not the issue.  When I use **ls -l -a**, I get all files listed in the same default color, while all directories are in blue.  I would like to get the invisible files shown with a magenta color, while all the others files stay in their basic color, and directories stay in blue.

Comment: The [`exa`](https://the.exa.website/) utility has several options for colorizing file listings; it may support what you're looking for.  There's also [`grc`](https://github.com/garabik/grc) which can colorize the output of many commands, including `ls`. Both can be installed via `homebrew`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ls` command is the only responsible with the appearance of what it prints. When `ls` is running, `zsh` only wait `ls` to exit. (The different color `zsh` options deal with what `zsh`prints).

On MacOS, the way to setup the different `ls` colors are presented here : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-terminal-color-ls-output-option/ See "Understanding LSCOLORS values" (`man ls` also show how colors are handled).

Unfortunately, you can't deal with the file/directory names, but only the kind of file (directory, socket, symbolic link, etc.) changes the color according to the palette you give.

One solution would be to use an other `ls` command, but the one from GNU doesn't seem to handle a `.*`pattern (about color handling). Only `*.extension`. Something like `LS_COLORS='.*=01;33' ls -a` indicates a unrecognized prefix. (Which is normal according to http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors)

Comment: Your first link just explains the `-G` option which the OP is already using, so I don't think it is adding anything useful.

Comment: I give the reference manual about color configuration, and this reference doesn't provide a way to handle colors like the OP want. I would have prefer the reference to have something more powerful, but the fact is that the ls coloring scheme of the Mac is too limited.

Comment: Yes, I am just talking about the first link (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-terminal-color-ls-output-option/). Since the only vaguely relevant part is that `-G` enables colored `ls` output which is already in the OP, I don't see why you would link to some random site for that instead of just mentioning `ls -G`, that's all.

Comment: I have edited the post to stress the "Understanding LSCOLORS values". It is the key point since it indicates THE variable used to indicate colors. And the way to do it doesn't permits to have a color dependant of the file/directory name.

Comment: So should I conclude there's currently no way to colorize the hidden files (i.e that begin with a dot) in the Terminal, independently of all the other normal files?  This seems odd to me.

Comment: Not with MacOS `ls`, nor with the GNU `ls`.

Comment: Oh well!  Thanks.  I'll forget my query, then...

Answer (score 1):

Note that while GNU `ls` colouring can only be done (via `$LS_COLORS` usually set with the help of the `dircolors` utility) based on file metadata or fixed suffix, [zsh completion colouring can be configured](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Colored-completion-listings) based on any pattern.

It extends GNU `ls`'s `$LS_COLORS` specification with `=pattern=attributes`. So with:

```
# set LS_COLORS for GNU ls
eval "$(dircolors)"

# use same colouring for completions, but also specify magenta for hidden files
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS} '=.*=35'
```

Or if you don't have GNU `ls` and `dircolors`, just:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS} '=.*=35'
```

(using the default colours for the rest which are similar to GNU `ls`').

That's using the more modern [list-colors zstyle](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-list_002dcolors_002c-completion-style), but the syntax is the same as for `$ZLS_COLORS`).

Then assuming you've enabled coloured completion via `compinstall` or manually, you'll see hidden files in magenta.

You'll likely also want to either enable the `globdots` aka `dotglob` option (which affects all glob expansions), or add:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns '*(D)'
```

For hidden files to be included by default in completion listings.

A minimum `~/.zshrc` to test that would look like:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors '=.*=35'
zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns '*(D)'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -i
```

But again, best would be to use `compinstall` to tune the completion system to your taste and add those two `list-colors` and `file-patterns` style separately.

In any case, that's only for zsh completion listing, that won't affect `ls` output.

Comment: I tried your last code.  It doesn't work.  I get that error message: command not found: dircolors

Comment: @Cham, `dircolors` comes with GNU `ls`, both part of GNU coreutils.